# mod_spdy cannot work on Apache

Tags: apache, spdy

I use mod_spdy to realize SPDY on apache. But I met some problems.
I did every step on ubuntu according to Google's document of installing mod_spdy.And I realized https on Apache. When I checked if mod_spdy has worked, I sent https request to the server, but I donot see server's domain listed in the "SPDY session" table that means the mod_spdy don't work. I also checked Apache server logs, and I didn't find any error message from mod_spdy.
I hope somebody can help me to deal with this problem.

Comment: side data: cPanel won't even support.